# Java ID3 calculating entropy

Tags: java, id3

I am implementing an ID3 and I am finding some variations in the entropy. Are the following two lines equivalent? Since I need Log to base 2, does the second one take it to base 10 by default?

```
entropy += -probability * (Math.log(probability) / Math.log(2));
```

and

```
entropy += -probability * (Math.log(probability));
```

Comment: The second one is log10 by default.  The first is correct, if you want to get the log2. You can create a method if you want: `double log2(double n) { return Math.log(n) / Math.log(2); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Math.log()` method gives log base 10.

Your first line calculates log base 2 by using a mathematical law: log<sub>a</sub>(x) = log<sub>b</sub>(x) / log<sub>b</sub>(a).

Answer (score 0):

See JavaDocs for: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log10(double)

> #### `public static double log10(double a)`
>
> Returns the base 10 logarithm of a double value. Special cases:
>
> - If the argument is NaN or less than zero, then the result is NaN.
> - If the argument is positive infinity, then the result is positive infinity.
> - If the argument is positive zero or negative zero, then the result is negative infinity.
> - If the argument is equal to 10n for integer n, then the result is n.
>
> The computed result must be within 1 ulp of the exact result. Results
>   must be semi-monotonic.
>
> #### Parameters:
>
> a - a value
>
> #### Returns:
>
> the base 10 logarithm of a.
>
> #### Since:
>
> 1.5

*"Returns the base 10 logarithm of a double value."*

You can create a static method called **`log2()`**

```
public static double log2(double n) {
    return Math.log(n) / Math.log(2);
}
```